# SQL SELECT from two tables - need join?

Tags: sql, select, join

How can i get all data from this 2 tables:

```
   Events
    cid   date
    1    1/12/2013
    2    2/2/2013
    1    5/5/2014

   Clients
    cid  name     gender
    1    david    male
    2    ashley   female
    3    barak    male
```

And i want to make request to get all events with the cid data like:

```
Final
   cid   date         name    gender
   1     1/12/2013    david   male
   2     2/2/2013     ashley  female
   1     5/5/2013     david   male
```

Comment: Yes, you need a join. [What have you tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)? Please post your query and explain what is not working and where you are stuck.

Comment: What do you mean when you SELECT * you get the id twice?  Your output above has cid twice?  Are you required to SELECT * vs. field names for some reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your requirement is SELECT * (why), then you could wrap all of the previous answers in a subquery.  Something like this:

```
select * from 
(
  SELECT
  E.cid, 
  date, 
  name, 
  gender
FROM Events E
LEFT JOIN Clients C
  ON E.cid = C.cid) t
```

And the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/830f4/4).

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from Events join Clients on Clients.cid = Events.cid;
```

Comment: The problem if i do SELECT * i get the id twice,can i get only one?

Comment: Then instead of using '*', simply specify the columns you want from each table.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  E.cid, 
  date, 
  name, 
  gender
FROM Events E
LEFT JOIN Clients C
  ON E.cid = C.cid
```

The Left Join takes care of where there is not an entry in Clients Table for an Event cid

If there is referential integrity between the tables and you can guarantee that there will be at least one entry in Clients Table then you can replace the LEFT JOIN with an INNER JOIN. But it all depends on what data you have and what your query constraints are.

**Never assume INNER JOIN unless you're sure you're not excluding pertinent data.**

Comment: The problem if i do SELECT * i get the id twice,can i get only one?

Comment: I'm not suggesting you do a select *

Answer (score 0):

You will want to `JOIN` the tables:

```
select e.cid,
  e.date,
  c.name,
  c.gender
from clients c
inner join events e
  on e.cid = c.cid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/830f4/2)

If you need help learning join syntax, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

I used an `INNER JOIN` to join the tables, which will return all rows in the `clients` table that has matching rows in the the `events` table. If you want to return all `clients` regardless of a row in the `events` table then you can use a `LEFT JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Tables are in first letter capitalized

```
SELECT e.cid, e.date, c.name, c.gender
FROM Events AS e
LEFT JOIN Clients AS c
ON e.cid = c.cid
```

Comment: The problem if i do SELECT * i get the id twice,can i get only one?

Comment: There's no reason to wrap it in another SELECT. That's just ridiculous.